# Prolog Graph Visualization

Tags: java, prolog, graphviz, swi-prolog, visualize

I have a Dijkstra code in Prolog which shows me the shortest path. Now I want to visualize the result as a graph. Since I am very new to Prolog I do not know how can I do it. Is Graphviz something which can help? Is there an example that help me to do it? Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 3):

Swish has a graphviz renderer.

http://swish.swi-prolog.org/example/render_graphviz.swinb

Comment: Thank you. That was a good website. That would be great if you could please provide me better examples with both .pl und .dot files. Because I am still a bit confused. Thank you.

Comment: But the linked website has a nice example with prolog and dot code?